# In the dataframe Error replacing values ​in all columns using ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

In a dataframe, I want to convert a negative number to an absolute value and multiply it by 100 for a positive number.

```
r
a  b  c
0.6 0 -0.1
0 -0.2 0.3

r %>%
  mutate(across(function(x) ifelse(x<0,-x,x*100)))
```

I get an error.

I want output

```
r
a b c
60 0 0.1
0 0.2 30
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question but I thought better to answer it anyway

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,1,-1,2,2,2), 
                 B = c(1,-2,3,1,2,3), 
                 C = c(1,2,3,1,2,3))

df %>% mutate(across(.fns = function(x) ifelse(x < 0, abs(x), x *10)))


#>   A  B  C
#>1 10 10 10
#>2 10  2 20
#>3  1 30 30
#>4 20 10 10
#>5 20 20 20
#>6 20 30 30
```